# Is it acceptable to use non-English references in a paper?

Tags: citations, journals

I have a paper extracted from my thesis. Since English is not my first language, a few of references are non-English. I have also designed a model based on those non-English references. Now, I want to send it to foreign journals and I think it will be rejected. Is it necessary to use just English references in my paper?

Comment: Using references in other languages is very common.

Comment: In English papers, we often see references in German, French, Spanish, etc.  But for references in different alphabets, in addition to the original I would include a transliteration of the Author's name and a translation of the title.  (Russian, Chinese, Arabic, Thai, etc.)

Answer (score 9):

You **must** use non-English references if you use non-English sources. Citing sources is about giving credit where it is due for the ideas you use in your paper: it doesn't matter what language those ideas came in.

Some journals may request parts of the citation to be translated (such as the title), but it's most important that readers can find the original source.

Comment: This is absolutely correct and I've upvoted, but I think what OP really wants to ask is "is it acceptable to use non-English sources", e.g. for textbook stuff where exactly the same information is available from many sources.  (And the answer in that case is "yes, it is perfectly acceptable".)